# Is it possible to give root access to some apps without unrooting smartphone?

Tags: applications, root-access, firewall, development

Is it possible to create an app to **bypath unrooted phone to will seen like rooted phone for those apps who needs root access** 
by that app one must be able to give permission to those specific apps who requires root access, without unrooting entire smartphone.

Comment: If you mean you want root for some apps with an unrooted phone: Nope, that's impossible. If youve rooted your device you can choose which apps are granted roor access but you cant give them what you dont have

Answer (score 1):

Your wording is not very clear, so I'll answer base on my understanding.

Nearly every root management app (or custom ROMs with root) allows you to deny root access to certain apps and grant for others. Of all those, SuperSU is the most functionally complete, however changing the management app requires the underlying binaries and stuff to be changed to match, and this is almost impossible if you're running some certain root management apps (namely, ones that do one-click-root).

You'll be able to spoof apps into thinking you have no root access by using Xposed framework and modules such as this one: [LINK: Xposed repo](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.devadvance.rootcloak2), however again, installing Xposed framework is not as easy on every device.

Deny + spoof should keep unwanted apps out of reach of the root realm. If there's anything wrong, do point out in the comment below.